# Docker Compose build command using Cache and not picking up changed files while copying to docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file comprising of two services (both based on a DockerFile). I have build the images once (using command: `docker-compose build`) and they were up and running once I ran this command (`docker-compose up`).
I had to change the source code used for one of the services, however, when I rebuilt the images (`docker-compose build`), the code changes were not reflected once I ran the services (`docker-compose up`).

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  serviceOne:
    build:
      context: ./ServerOne
      args:
          PORT: 4000
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    env_file:
      - ./ServerOne/.env
    environment:
      - PORT=4000
  serviceTwo:
    build:
      context: ./serviceTwo
      args:
          PORT: 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - ./serviceTwo/.env
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - serviceOne_URL=http://serviceOne:4000/
    depends_on:
      - serviceOne
```

**serviceOne/DockerFile**

```
FROM node:8.10.0

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/
RUN npm build
EXPOSE ${ACC_PORT}
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**serviceTwo/DockerFile**

```
FROM node:8.10.0

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/
RUN npm build
EXPOSE ${ACC_PORT}
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Following is the output of the `docker-compose` when it is ran for the second time.
It is some how using the cached images again when **COPY** and **npm build** command are ran.

How could the **DockerFile** or **docker-compose** file be changed so that the new source code is deployed?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can force the build to ignore the cache by adding on the [--no-cache option to the docker-compose build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/)

Comment: But that will reduce the performance (Running all commands and creating the subsequent images for each command), is there some other way round?

Comment: Yes, the build will be a little slower. But it will have the latest code.